# For/While loops triangle in Python not working

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

Working on my 2nd triangle but it is not giving me the result needed using the while nested loop and I should have the following output.

Using for loop:

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
```

Using while loops:

```
     5
    45
   345
  2345
 12345
012345
```

Code:

```
print('Using for loop')
print()
M = 6 #constant
cnt = 1

for i in range(0,M):
    for j in range(0,cnt):
        if(j<M):
            print(j,'',end='')
        else:
            print('',end='')
    cnt+=1
    print()
print()
print('Using While loop')
print()
cnt = 6

while(cnt != -1):
    for j in range(0,cnt-1):
        if(j<cnt+1):
            print(j,'',end='')
        else:
            print(j)
    cnt -=1
    print()
print()
```

my current results are..

Using for loop

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
```

Using while loop

```
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

Comment: Your while loop has a lot of syntax error.

Comment: I am not sure about the restrictions of the problem given to you, but shouldn't your while-loop code be using only while-loops and not a for-loop?

Comment: See the syntax errors, now. Thx @skaul05.

Comment: Yes @gdef_ I am only to use while-loops..not for-loops in there. :-) Thx for your feedback. Newbie here and it is proving to be very interesting.

Comment: Great, i added a solution with only while loops for the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lot of syntax error use this

```
print('Using for loop')
print()
M = 6 #constant
cnt = 1

for i in range(0,M):
    for j in range(0,cnt):
        if(j<M):
            print(j,'',end='')
    cnt+=1
    print()
print('\nUsing While loop\n')
cnt = 0

while(cnt != M):
    for j in range(0,M-(cnt+1)):
        print(' ','',end='')
    for j in range(0,cnt+1):
        print(M-(cnt+1-j),'',end='')
    cnt +=1
    print()
print()
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. Also you have many syntax errors. Use this:

```
print('Using While loop')
print()
cnt = 6
v = cnt
while(cnt != -1):
    print(' ' * cnt, end='')
    for j in range(cnt, v):
        if j < cnt+1:
            print(j, end='')
        else:
            print(j, end='')
    cnt -=1
    print()
```

**Output**:

```
Using While loop

     5
    45
   345
  2345
 12345
012345
```

Comment: Thank you for your time...will compare my work and learn where I went wrong. Also, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a while-loop solution without any for-loop:

```
print('Using While loop')
print()
cnt = 6
v = cnt
while(cnt != -1):
    j = cnt
    print(' ' * cnt, end='')
    while(j < v):
        print(j, end='')
        j += 1

    cnt -=1
    print()
```